# How to make vertex and fragment shaders work in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Have started working my way through a book called WebGL: Up and Running, which uses my preferred solution of THREE.js for rendering 3D objects in the browser.  I'm trying to emulate the part of the book where he introduces shaders to make a dynamic, lit sun, but all I get when I try is a black sphere.  Making the shader something more simple (like a Lampert shader) works fine, so it doesn't seem to be lighting - just the way the shader is implemented.

So what am I doing wrong?  My javascript code to set up the scene is

```
var renderer, scene, camera, sunMesh, clock, uniforms;

$(function(){          

    //set scene size
    var WIDTH = 1200,
            HEIGHT = 800;

    //set some camera attributes
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
        ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
        NEAR = 0.1,
        FAR = 10000;

    // get the DOM element to attach to
    // - assume we've got jQuery to hand
    var $container = $('#container');

    // create a WebGL renderer, camera
    // and a scene
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  VIEW_ANGLE,
                                    ASPECT,
                                    NEAR,
                                    FAR  );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
    camera.position.z = 300;

    // start the renderer
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // attach the render-supplied DOM element
    $container.append(renderer.domElement);

    // Create a group to hold our sun mesh and light
    var sunGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
    var SUNMAP = "./images/lavatile.jpg";
    var NOISEMAP = "./images/cloud.png";
    uniforms = {
            time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
            texture1: { type: "t", value: 0, texture: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( NOISEMAP ) },
            texture2: { type: "t", value: 1, texture: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( SUNMAP ) }
    };

    uniforms.texture1.texture.wrapS = uniforms.texture1.texture.wrapT = THREE.Repeat;
    uniforms.texture2.texture.wrapS = uniforms.texture2.texture.wrapT = THREE.Repeat;
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
    } );

    //USING THIS MATERIAL WORKS, SO ITS DEFINITELY THE SHADER!
    //var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
    //{
    //    color: 0x5B92E5
    //});


    // Create our sun mesh
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 64, 64);
    sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    // Tuck away the uniforms so that we can animate them over time
    // Set up a clock to drive the animation
    clock = new THREE.Clock();
    // Create a point light to show off our solar system
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set(0,0,100);
    sunGroup.add(sunMesh);
    sunGroup.add(light);
    scene.add(sunGroup);
    // and the camera
    scene.add(camera);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // setup an interval to loop the game loop
    setInterval(gameloop, 50);     

});

function gameloop() {  
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    uniforms.time.value += delta;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I'll save the full HTML (listed at http://pastebin.com/PGLXkzkA) but that contains my shaders, which I've lifted from the source of the WebGL book.  It may be that these are wrong, but I'm suspecting it is the way I'm using the shaders.  From what I understand, I should see a sun with the textures changing based on a noise occlusion map, with some movement in the vertex position to make the sun pulse.  As I say, I can see a sphere, but it is unlit and black.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a shame. This book appears to be already out-of-date.

Three.js is in alpha, and is changing rapidly. **Learn from the three.js examples, instead.** They are always current.

Check out the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help in upgrading to the current version.

Some obvious errors in your code:

```
texture1: { type: "t", value: 0, texture: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( NOISEMAP ) },
```

should be

```
texture1: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( NOISEMAP ) },
```

`THREE.Repeat` should be `THREE.RepeatWrapping`, and `uniforms.texture1.texture` should be `uniforms.texture1.value`.

Sorry, you may have other issues, but I can only help you with the current version of three.js.

three.js r.54

Comment: Thanks for that - I'd feared as much. Will scour the API for these, but the docs on ShaderMaterial are hard/impossible to find.

Comment: I recently posted some simple shader examples at http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Shader-Simple.html and http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Shader-Explorer.html, its no substitute for docs but it might be enough to get you started. Good luck!